# conditional Probability proof with inequalities

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Let A, B be events taken from a sample space Ω (with Pr(A) > 0 and Pr(B) > 0). If
Pr(B|A) < Pr(B), prove that Pr(A|B) < Pr(A).  I am a bit confused with this one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Using the definition of conditional probability,
$$P(B\,|\,A)<P(B)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}<P(B)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad P(B\cap A)<P(A)P(B)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$P[B\vert A]<P[B]$$ is equivalent to $$P[B\cap A]<P[A]P[B]$$ (multiply both sides by $P[A]>0$).

Answer (score 0):

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}<P(B)\implies \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}<P(A)\implies P(A|B)<P(A)$$